# How to simulate button clicking by using Shortcut?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt-quick

I have a kind of handmade button:

```
Rectangle {

    // ...

    Text {
        // ...
    }

    Shortcut {
        sequence: if (number!=12) "F"+number
        onActivated: (valve.opened) ? valve.open() : valve.close()
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: (valve.opened) ? valve.open() : valve.close()
        onPressed: parent.color = (valve.opened) ? "forestgreen" : "grey"
        onReleased: parent.color = (valve.opened) ? "lightgreen" : "#A8A8A8"
    }
}
```

Pressing this button with a mouse changes the button's background color, and releasing returns its natural color (looks like a behavior of an usual button).

[image]

The button also has its shortcut. How can I add similar behavior to `Shortcut`, that is, to change a button's color while I'm pressing some keyboard shortcut, then changing color after releasing the button? Now it just performs the action of this button.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcuts are just triggered (multiple times) and do not have a notion of being pressed. You should implement it yourself using `Keys.onPressed` and `Keys.onReleased`, see [Keys](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-keys.html) for more information.